# HTML5 Canvas DataURLs are not the same when I compare them? (javascript/jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I've got a javascript/Jquery function that looks like this:

```
function loadRawData()

canvasData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

rawData = $('#imgInput').val();


//check the raw data box is not empty or identical to the canvas
if(rawData == ""){
    console.log("Raw data box is empty!");
}else if(rawData != canvasData){

//WHY ARE THEY DIFFERENT???
    alert(canvasData);
    alert(rawData);
///////////////////////////

    // load image from data url
    raw = new Image();
    raw.src = rawData;
    raw.onload = function() {
        //Clear canvas for the new image
        clearCanvas();

        context.drawImage(raw, 0, 0);
    }

    console.log("Canvas restored to rawData");

}else{
 console.log("Canvas failed to restore (same as canvas?)");
}
}
```

When my function is called it loads the data all fine and well from a textarea with the ID of 'imgInput' and shows the picture I tried to load; But when I call it immediately after, it passes true through the else if even though the two variables are SUPPOSED to be identical..

I made two alert boxes to look at the data for each variable and sure enough, the canvas' URL and the raw data's URL are completely different, however the picture that loads is the same.

What's going on? I can't figure out where I messed up?
Thank you in advance for any advice you can provide =)

Comment: Supposing the sizes are the same, what made you thing they would be equal ? Is there a spec backing that ? There are more than one way to encode in png an image.

Comment: dystroy is correct, this is not a realistic scenario. Different implementations of PNG generating might use different compression levels/variations of algorithms, and also meta data embedded in your original image data (f.e. EXIF, ...) will of course not be present in what `toDataURL` returns.

Comment: @destroy well, I'm still learning how this works, but when I call my function over and over the two resulting values are the same every time.

The image that I'm loading and saving and re-loading is the same one every time and does not change. 

Literally, i'm saving the canvas and then re-loading it and checking if the two values are the same (Which in my mind they should be pixel-for-pixel identical)

Comment: You mean you fill the #imgInput input with the data you get in the browser ?

Comment: @destroy I'm literally putting the data into the #imgInput and re-loading it to see if it's identical (which it should be, if this is working how I think it does?)

Comment: If you take some dataurl generated somewhere, you take it in your browser as the src of an image, there is no reason the PNG encoding will reproduce the dataurl you started with. For many reasons, from alpha management to metadata or zip compression algorithm.

Comment: @destroy I'm not sure if you're not understanding my problem, or if i'm not understanding what you're trying to tell me, but I feel there's a slight miscommunication somewhere and I apologize. let me try to clarify,   I  am saving my canvas to data URL, putting that URL into #imgData and checking to see if the canvas URL data is identical to the URL I just entered into #imgData. Then if they are not identical, drawing that image onto the canvas. rinse and repeat. When I repeatedly call my function, the else if passes true. (but it's the same image...?)

Comment: Are your saving your canvas to data URL on the same browser with the same canvas ?

Comment: @destroy    yes. I'm literally clicking a button over and over that calls this function and it is passing the  console.log over and over for each click, indicating the if else passed true.

Comment: Ca you reproduce your problem in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle) to remove all possible misunderstanding ?

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/x3n8s/)